# Cache Analysis - Computer Architecture

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

This a problem in a computer architecture course that's giving me some trouble:

You have an application whose memory access pattern is a stream and its entire data set is 128kB. The data cache in  your machine has a capacity of 64kB. It is word-addressable and direct-mapped with 32B lines. It is able to fetch one line at a time.

Given the access pattern: 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, …, 32768, where each access is a 4B word.

1. What is the miss rate?
2. Can the miss rate be reduced by using a larger cache?
3. Can the miss rate be reduced if the size of the data set were reduced?

Here's what I think is going on:  The cache is initially empty, meaning each access will result in a compulsory miss.  So would this mean the miss rate is 100%, since no data is initially loaded and the pattern doesn't hit any address twice?

Any help understanding this would be much appreciated!

Comment: This question was answered in Computer Science at:

http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28248/calculating-miss-rates-of-word-addressable-and-direct-mapped-cache

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your cache lines are 32B long, which means when you load address 0, you receive addresses 4,8,...,28 and all of those will hit in the cache. so your miss rate will be 4/32 = 1/8 = 12.5%. Larger cache or reducing the data set would not help, because all of your misses are compulsory misses. But adding a prefetcher would help reduce the miss rate.

Comment: +1 This answer is useful, but it *might* help to explain a little why all the misses are first access/compulsory misses (streaming access without repeated references).